# ylabel location in stacked subplots in julia

Tags: matplotlib, julia

Is there a way to center align y-label in row-wise stack plots in Julia

[image: stacked subplot]

```py
pyplot(grid=:false, frame=:box)
x=LinRange(-π,π,1000)
p1=plot(x,10*sin.(10*x), xticks=:false,yticks=:false,ylabel="Intensity")
p2=plot(x,exp.(x),xlabel=L"\theta",yticks=:false)
plot!(p1,p2,layout=(2,1),link=:all,top_margin=-1mm)
```

Y label is positioned at the top. How to place it at center

Comment: Matplotlib has supylabel.  I don’t know how to pass that through to the Julia layer

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
pyplot(grid=:false, frame=:box)
x=LinRange(-π,π,1000)
p1=plot(x,10*sin.(10*x), xticks=:false,yticks=:false,ylabel="Intensity")
p2=plot(x,exp.(x),xlabel="θ",yticks=:false)
plot!(p1,p2,layout=(2,1),link=:all, 
legend=:top
)
```

[image]

Or use `:left` to center vertical on the y-axis.